# Replace 2 terms in one go?

Tags: eclipse

Happy eclipse mars user here.

I often copy & paste code from one class file to another. Next i replace keywords with new keywords, for example i replace:

```
User with Box
user with box
```

I use "find and replace" dialog (CTRL+F) to do the replace.

Now i enter "User" in "Find" field and "Box" in "replace with" field, and next i do the same with "user" and "box".

Is it possible to replace "User" with "Box" and "user" with "box" in one go?

Comment: So this has nothing to do with java? Then remove the java tag please.

Comment: You might want to look into refactoring, tends to be a lot cleaner than copying and pasting:
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-refactor.htm

Comment: @Draken refactoring is quite a lenghty process, i for example have user/User which needs to be replaced in classname, function names, variables, strings and such. With refactoring i have to click many times on different things, with "find and replace" i can do all that in one go.

Comment: @f1sh whoops, thumbs up Maroun Maroun for removing it!

Answer (score 0):

you can not do "find and replace" in one go as eclipse support reg expression in find string , but not in replace string. 
Better you do it by refactoring or you can do "find and replace" one by one by keeping Case sensitive check on.

Comment: Cheers, i can do (U|u)ser and replace it with $1ox , this results in Uox or uox, but i can't seem to find a way to replace U or u with B or b. I guess it indeed is not possible to do this in one go while using regexes.